# VS Code shortcut to add delimiters to selected words

Tags: visual-studio-code, quarto

I am using [`quarto`](https://quarto.org/docs/tools/vscode.html) on VS Code, and need a keyboard shortcut to add delimiters to a *selected* word or words. For instance, considering the words

thank you

the keyboard shortcut should return

`thank you`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

define the following key binding

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+k ctrl+i",  // or any other combo
  "command": "editor.action.insertSnippet",
  "when": "editorTextFocus",
  "args": {
    "snippet": "`${TM_SELECTED_TEXT}`$0"
  }
}
```

Select the text and press key binding.

Answer (score 0):

Not a fail-safe solution, but you can always use the 'global search & replace' option of VS-code. To limit the amount of hits, you can put a filter on which files to include in the search.

A shortcut for this is `cmd + shift + r` on Mac or `control + shift + r` on Windows

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Kasteelbier, for your answer! rioV8's solution is fail-safe.

Comment: Indeed! Learned something as well here!